# Unable to queryDocuments using a CosmosDb Sproc

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to create a sproc in my cosmosdb collection, but am unable to successfully execute any query as shown in the examples:

1. QueryDocuments api - https://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html
2. Example for using QueryDocuments - https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/SimpleScript.js

I wrote my own sproc based off of SimpleScript.js that looks like

```
    function() { 
        function callback(err, docs, opt)
        {
            if (err) getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(err));
            else getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(opt).concat(JSON.stringify(docs)));
        }
        var collection = getContext().getCollection();
        var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
        var x = __.queryDocuments(__.getSelfLink(),{ query: "select * from root r"},callback);
    }
```

I'm using DocumentDbStudio 0.72 to create the sproc, and run it. 
This is the response body I get (from setBody in the callback function):

`{"currentCollectionSizeInMB":"documentSize=0;documentsSize=98;documentsCount=14;collectionSize=101;","maxCollectionSizeInMB":"documentSize=0;documentsSize=98;documentsCount=14;collectionSize=101;"}[]`

How do I successfully create such a Select * sproc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took your script and it worked well on my side.

[image]

So, could you double check whether you have any docs in the collection by using **Query Explorer** in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

[image]